# Convert stringified numbers back to number

Tags: javascript

I am having numbers that are stringified, such as `["84.0711 billion", "$52.6138 billion", "$43.55 billion", "$54.73 million"]`. I would like to convert these numbers back to: `["84071100000", "52613800000", "43550000000", "54730000"]`

```js
let numb = ["84.0711 billion", "$52.6138 billion", "$43.55 billion", "$54.73 million"]
const res = []

for (let i = 0; i < numb.length; i++) {
  res.push(convertNumber(numb[i]))
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
//wanted output: ["84071100000", "52613800000", "43550000000", "54730000"]


function convertNumber(numb) {
  var digits = numb.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
  if (numb.match('billion')) digits + 1000000000
  if (numb.match('million')) digits + 1000000
  return digits
}
```

I tried to get only the digits and then add the respective notation. However, I only get the following output.(see above my example)

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a single regex

```js
let numb = ["84.0711 billion", "$52.6138 billion", "$43.55 billion", "$54.73 million"]

const conversion = {
    billion: 1000000000,
    million: 1000000
};

function convert(entry) {
    return entry.replace(/^\$?(\S+)\s?(\w+)/g, (a, n, e) => {
        return Number(n) * conversion[e];
    })
}

console.log(convert(numb[0]));
```

Comment: You could use `\S+` instead of `\d+\.?\d+` if you know it only has digits and no whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the dot and decimals after the dot as well and multiply the value and assign the result to digits.

Then you could seach for the wanted factor and take a default value for multiplying.

```js
function convert(string) {
    var factors = { million: 1e6, billion: 1e9 },
        value = string.match(/\d+\.?\d*/g),
        factor = string.match(new RegExp(Object.keys(factors).join('|'), 'i'));

    return (value || 0) * (factors[factor] || 1);
}

var strings = ["84.0711 billion", "$52.6138 billion", "$43.55 billion", "$54.73 million"],
    result = strings.map(convert);

console.log(result); // [84071100000, 52613800000, 43550000000, 54730000]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `replace()`

`replace(/[^\d.]/g, '')` - remove everything except numbers and dot

`+numb` - unary plus converts string to Number

```js
let numb = ["84.0711 billion", "$52.6138 billion", "$43.55 billion", "$54.73 million"]
const res = []

for (let i = 0; i < numb.length; i++) {
  res.push(convertNumber(numb[i]))
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));

function convertNumber(numb) {
  var digits = +numb.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
  if (numb.match('billion')) digits = digits * 1000000000
  if (numb.match('million')) digits = digits * 1000000
  return digits
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close, actually but there are few minor issues:

- the regex  `/\d+/g` will fail you because it only finds digits but you also have `.` as a decimal separator. So you need to account for it in the pattern - `/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g` - it's any number of digits, optionally followed by a literal dot and then any number of digits again.

  - the regex result gives you an array with all the matches. You only want the number, so you can get it by doing `[0]`
  - `if (numb.match('billion')) digits + 1000000000` you actually want to multiply, not add. Because `1.21 thousand` is `1.21 * 1000 = 1210` not `1.21 + 1000 = 1001.21`
  - you need to assign the value back to the `digits` - `digits * 1000000000` will perform the operation but will then discard the result - if you do `digits = digits * 1000000000` then it will be saved. You can also write that as `digits *= 1000000000` - multiply the value and assign it back.
  - instead of `matches` use `includes`. It's a bit simpler to use - it will check if the string has the value you want, while `matches` will try to run it against a regex, which is a bit less predictable if you have, say, `.` or brackets.

```js
let numb = ["84.0711 billion", "$52.6138 billion", "$43.55 billion", "$54.73 million"]
const res = []

for (let i = 0; i < numb.length; i++) {
  res.push(convertNumber(numb[i]))
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
//wanted output: ["84071100000", "52613800000", "43550000000", "54730000"]


function convertNumber(numb) {
  var digits = numb
    .match(/\d+(?:\.\d+)/g)
    .map(Number)[0];
    
  if (numb.includes('billion')) digits *= 1000000000
  if (numb.includes('million')) digits *= 1000000
  return digits
}
```